# Use C++ DLL in C#

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke

My program need control a hardware. Vendor provide a DLL which is design for C/C++ language.
Most of functions passed my test beside below function:

```
int32 ni845xSpiWriteRead(NiHandle DeviceHandle,
                         NiHandle ConfigurationHandle,
                         uInt32   WriteSize,
                         uInt8  * pWriteData,
                         uInt32 * pReadSize,
                         uInt8  * pReadData);
```

Document of this function is here:

- Inputs NiHandle DeviceHandle

  Device handle returned from ni845xOpen.
- NiHandle ConfigurationHandle

  The configuration handle returned from ni845xSpiConfigurationOpen.
- uInt32 WriteSize

  The number of bytes to write. This must be nonzero.
- uInt8 * pWriteData

  The data bytes to be written.
- Outputs uInt32 * pReadSize

  A pointer to the amount of bytes read.
- uInt8 * pReadData

  A pointer to an array of bytes where the bytes that have been read
  are stored.

My code in C# is here:

```
[DllImport("Ni845x", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int ni845xSpiWriteRead(
                                                long DeviceHandle, //In 
                                                long ConfigurationHandle, //In
                                                int WriteSize, //In
                                                IntPtr pWriteData, //In
                                                IntPtr pReadSize, //Out
                                                IntPtr pReadData //Out
                                                );
```

I always got `AccessViolationException` exception. I am guessing that is caused by the pointer input/output parameter.

The code of invoke Swrapper.ni845xSpiWriteRead() i here:

```
public void WriteData(int length, int[] writeArray)
        {
            byte[] writeDate = new byte[8];

            int writeSize = writeDate.Length;

            try
            {
                //Define pointers
                IntPtr writeDataPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(writeDate.Length);
                IntPtr readDataSizePointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(writeDate.Length);
                IntPtr readDataPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(writeDate.Length);

                //Copy value to write data pointer
                Marshal.Copy(writeDate, 0, writeDataPointer, writeDate.Length);

                int state = Ni845xNativeMethods.ni845xSpiWriteRead(_niHandle, _niConfigrationHandle, writeSize, writeDataPointer,readDataSizePointer,readDataPointer);

                this.CheckStatus(state);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Well perhaps you should show us how you call it.  Also, is this C++ (as you say in your title) or C (as you tagged it)?  If it's a C++ DLL with a C interface just leave the C++ out.

Comment: I don't think your `DllImport` is well written. I suggest you try the following:

    `[DllImport("Ni845x", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int ni845xSpiWriteRead(
        IntPtr DeviceHandle, //In 
        IntPtr ConfigurationHandle, //In
        uint WriteSize, //In
        IntPtr pWriteData, //In
        ref uint pReadSize, //Out
        IntPtr pReadData //Out
    );`

It is important though how you pass the arguments, especially `pWriteData` and `pReadData`. Show us code.

Comment: you may write some wrapper c++ dll for hardware dll.

Comment: @prasathviki: Not needed. Interop can easily handle stuff like this, but the exception is in code we haven't been shown yet.

Comment: @EdS. I am not sure the DLL is created by C or C++. That is provide by NI (hardware vendor). It should be C DLL as your comment

Comment: Hi @MariusBancila the code i invoke swrapper method is uploaded, please advise

Comment: NI documentation on this API can be found here, for anybody curious: http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/371746d.pdf

Comment: You never use the parameter `int[] writeArray`, and the contents of `writeDate` is always an 8-element array of zeros.

Comment: Also, are you sure that this is `CallingConvention.Cdecl`? That would be my first guess, but you should look at the library documentation and headers to see if it's supposed to be `StdCall`.

Comment: What is the actual underlying type of NiHandle?

Comment: Does the code shown still accurately represent your calling code?  If so, you are still not providing the pReadSize parameter correctly.

Comment: Did you copy the C function declaration from the documentation or from the header file?  If it was from the documentation, they may have left out key information, such as whether the calling convention should be CDECL or STDCALL.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the p/invoke should be:

```
[DllImport("Ni845x", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int ni845xSpiWriteRead(
    IntPtr DeviceHandle,
    IntPtr ConfigurationHandle,
    uint WriteSize,
    [In] byte[] WriteData,
    out uint ReadSize,
    [Out] byte[] ReadData
);
```

You'll need to allocate a `byte[]` of sufficient length to use as the `ReadData` parameter. Presumably you know how to do this.

I've taken at face value the statement that `ReadSize` is an output parameter. However, if it is both in and out, then declare it as `ref`.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely thing is it's just the Out size parameter. So:

```
[DllImport("Ni845x", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int ni845xSpiWriteRead(
                                            long DeviceHandle, //In 
                                            long ConfigurationHandle, //In
                                            int WriteSize, //In
                                            IntPtr pWriteData, //In
                                            out uint ReadSize, //Out
                                            IntPtr pReadData //Out
                                            );
```

This is similar to @Marius, but the handles should be fine as integers. The trick is to get the size returned as an integer, so either 'out uint' or 'ref uint' to do that.

Much better if we could see the calling code.

---

Having seen the code, you could also try something like this.

```
[DllImport("Ni845x", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int ni845xSpiWriteRead(
  long DeviceHandle, //In 
  long ConfigurationHandle, //In
  int WriteSize, //In
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] long [] writeData, //In
  out uint ReadSize, //Out
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray), Out] readData //Out
);
```

This avoids all that Marshal.Copy stuff. Make sure the `readData` buffer is big enough.

Comment: Hi Dave, the caller program have been uploaded, please advise.

Comment: `long` is 64 bits wide

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: So what? Some code not seen by us gets that handle value from somewhere else, and it's highly likely it's already working as it is. Changing it to IntPtr means you have to change other code. For a genuine C handle, there is no reason to use IntPtr because you don't know that it is a pointer. It could be anything.

Comment: On a 32 bit machine, it will be the wrong size. There is no reason to use IntPtr? That makes no sense. Genuine C handle? What is that precisely? What type is a genuine C handle?

Comment: @david.pfx I tested your suggestion today. Still get same exception...Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is, we're now into debugging. The answers provided here most likely have the information needed to make this thing work, but Interop requires a pretty solid understanding of the underlying C code and how to use the tools available to diagnose and fix bugs. I think all of us who have given answers could do that, but based on maybe 10+ years of experience. I don't think there is much more I can add short of a remote control interactive debugging session. And that's not what SO is about. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think both of the existing answers are somewhat incorrect, so I will add another (probably also incorrect) answer.

If DeviceHandle and ConfigurationHandle are truly HANDLE types (or other pointer types) then you should use IntPtr as the type for P/Invoke.

Given the C function declaration, the ReadData buffer must be allocated by the caller.  Also, it is likely that ReadSize must be initialized to the size of the buffer and will be set to the actual number of bytes read during the function call.

I think this may come close to working:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("Ni845x", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int ni845xSpiWriteRead(
        IntPtr DeviceHandle,
        IntPtr ConfigurationHandle,
        UInt32 WriteSize,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)][In] Byte[] pWriteData,
        ref UInt32 ReadSize,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)][Out] Byte[] pReadData);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntPtr DeviceHandle = (IntPtr)123;
        IntPtr ConfigurationHandle = (IntPtr)456;
        Byte[] WriteData = new Byte[2324];
        Byte[] ReadData = new Byte[8274];
        UInt32 ReadSize = (UInt32)ReadData.Length;

        int result = ni845xSpiWriteRead(DeviceHandle,
                                        ConfigurationHandle,
                                        (UInt32) WriteData.Length,
                                        WriteData,
                                        ref ReadSize,
                                        ReadData);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this different from my answer, that you declare to be incorrect? The ReadSize param is documented as being an output parameter. I guess it could go either way.

Comment: @David Heffernan Yes, the concern I had with your answer was that, conventionally for this sort of API, the ReadSize parameter would initially contain the size of the read buffer and then be set to the actual bytes read.

Comment: My answer covers that now. You should have said that in your answer, or even just commented on mine.

Comment: I tried as your suggestion, same exception (AccessViolationException). It's hard to tell which parameter is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Change your calling convention from Cdecl to stdCall and it will work now.
[DllImport("Ni845x", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).